# How to use std::for_each on a member function

Tags: c++, stl

I am trying to pick up the more 'functional' style of STL programming, and have the following simplified case

```
class Widget;

class Zot
{
public:
  std::vector<Widget> Widgets;

  void ProcessAWidget(int x, Widget w) { ... }

  void Process()
  {
      int ctx=123;

      std::for_each(Widgets.begin(), Widgets.end(), 
           std::bind(&Zot::ProcessAWidget, this, ctx, _1));
   }
};
```

Is there a better way of writing the last parameter for the for_each call?

In particular having to explicitly mention this feels 'wrong', and dropping the class qualifier would be good too.

Comment: Anyone care to add a non-C++11 alternative answer? Unfortunately, many of us are limited to working in 'behind the curve' environments.

Comment: The boost function library may be of use -- I don't remember if it is compatible with the foreach algorithm though.  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/function/tutorial.html#id1545718

Comment: @Component10: There is no non-C++11 alternative. The class must be explicit when taking a pointer-to-member, and the object on which the pointer to member is to be applied must also be there. That is carefully hidden in the lambda... but must be explicit in C++03 [BTW, without C++11 there is no `std::bind` to start with]

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Thanks. That would be why I never use `std::for_each` - too much `std::mem_fun` froth - roll on C++11.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the compiler supports C++11 lambdas:

```
std::for_each(Widgets.begin(),
              Widgets.end(),
              [&](Widget& a_w) { ProcessAWidget(ctx, a_w); });
```

Answer (score 7):

Lambdas to the rescue:

```
std::for_each(Widgets.begin(), Widgets.end(),
              [=](Widget & w) { ProcessAWidget(ctx, w); });
```

Comment: How can you call `ProcessAWidget` from the lambda? `this` is not captured.

Comment: A lambda is definitely more obvious that the bind. Though in the real world case I have it is more characters than the bind due to the length of the type names involved.  Replacing the 'Widget' in the lambda signature with 'auto' doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: [=] captures by value - is that what you meant?

Answer (score 2):

In C++11, you can use a lambda function with std::for_each, which often makes the code much more readable than the games you have to play with std::bind.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution:

until c++11

```
    std::for_each( container.cbegin(), container.cend(), std::bind1st(std::mem_fun(&MyClass::method), this) );
```

after:

```
    std::for_each( container.cbegin(), container.cend(),std::bind(&MyClass::method, this,  std::placeholders::_1));
```